# AWS-SDK: SQS How identify messages that were not deleted in BatchDeleteOperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

```
deleteMessagesParams := &sqs.DeleteMessageBatchInput{
        Entries:  messagesToDelete, // array of type *sqs.DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry
        QueueUrl: aws.String(QUEUE_URL),
}

if resp , err := svc.DeleteMessageBatch(deleteMessagesParams); err != nil {
    log.Println("Batch Delete Failed: ", err.Error())
}else{
     log.Println("Batch Delete Successful: ", resp)
}
```

I'm using batch delete in SQS. When the batch deletion operation is successful, resp contains the MessageId's of messages for which deletion is successful.

In-case of error or when some messages are not deleted from the queue, will the err contain MessageId's for which batch Deletion failed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of partial success when performing batch deletes, the service would return a 200 ok and the response object will have two fields Successful and Failed.

The Failed will have list of "BatchResultErrorEntry" type of objects containing the message ids and reason for failures.

Comment: How can I create a scenario for partial success and test it?

Comment: Try sending a invalid msg id in the batch delete request.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all failed messages using the [`DeleteMessageBatchResult.getFailed()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/DeleteMessageBatchResult.html#getFailed--) method call.